# How can i get inline abbreviation element suggestions like this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emmet, abbreviation

I tried with emmet setting in 'json' but not getting suggestions

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "javascript": "jsx",
    "jsx": {
      "inlineElements": ["input", "img", "id", "name"]
    }
  }
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAQBQ.png) and i need suggestion like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Jkk.png)
need suggestions like above images

Answer (score 0):

for the first image, these are called snippets, you can easily add them
click `ctrl + shift + p` to open commands pallet, then type `>Snippets: Configure User Snippets` and enter, then you will have options to create snippets either for the current workspace or global ones

once you hit enter, the explanation on how to add a snippet will be a comment on the file

for the second image, these suggestions are shown by intillisense, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSPHucggmLo) video for better understanding